# Manual semaphore in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to put a time-constrained semaphore into a sql database. The lock shall provide mutual exclusion on write access to a data table, but concerning only a certain FK value (email), which is why I can't use table locks or similar. And since I don't trust the sql connection to hold or the lock to be released in all cases (of course we try, but better safe than sorry), the lock shall time out after 3 minutes if it is not renewed or released in between.

Up to now, I have the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE users SET lockTime = GETDATE() OUTPUT DELETED.LockTime WHERE email = @mail
```

The problem: If the user is in the table, this will always update the lockTime and return the old lockTime. So, if an orphaned lock is in effect and the query is run in 2-minute intervals, the lock will never be released. (For testing all the logic around it, this is okay, but not for production.)

The lockTime should only be updated if it is older than, say, 3 minutes. So I tried:

```
UPDATE users SET lockTime = GETDATE() OUTPUT DELETED.LockTime 
WHERE email = @mail AND DATEADD(lockTime,'3 minutes')<GETDATE()
```

But this can't even be put into testing code, since I can't distinguish the cases "email is not in DB" and "lock is younger than 3 minutes".

So, where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to do this using just usual locking. In fact, you'll need to use that anyway, because your version isn't actually thread-safe - it still allows two separate commands to change the email at the same time.

Comment: @Luaan "change the email at the same time" - how so, isn't a single update operation atomic?

Comment: It is, although that isn't always enough. I'm not sure what my original problem with your query was in this way, perhaps I misread something. Still, why exactly can't you use a `rowlock,updlock`? Do you want other updates to the row to be done in parallel while you're doing some other work?

Comment: @Luaan The row contains the LastAccessTime that is updated whenever a read access occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do better:

```
UPDATE users
SET lockTime = 
CASE WHEN DATEADD(lockTime,'3 minutes')<GETDATE() THEN GETDATE()
ELSE lockTime END
OUTPUT DELETED.LockTime
WHERE email = @mail
```

Where we're using `CASE` to decide whether to actually update `lockTime`.